# How to Implement POST Method in RESTFul web services using Jersey

Tags: web-services

I have been working on simple RESTFul Web Services lately, with jersey on Eclipse. I can get the GET Functions to work just fine. But when I try POST Methods, using the Post annotation and deploy it, I get the "method not allowed" message. I can't seem to figure out why. Any idea on how I can get it to work?

Thank you.

Here is my Code:-

```
package myapp;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("login")
public class SimpleClass {
    @POST
    @Path("/sayhello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
public String sayHello(@QueryParam("username") String username)
{
    return "Hello  "+username;
}
}
```

And accessed through the link as:
 http://localhost:8080/RestSample/login/sayhello?username=som

And I get the "method not allowed" message.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing from browser , so default method for browser is **GET**

try to invoke from and ReST client like **POSTMAN**
where you can change method to POST

Comment: Thankx for suggestion sir,but I don't wanna use GET because it is not so secure.

Comment: I am not saying to use GET

Answer (score 0):

### Explaining the 405 error

When typing the resource URL in the browser address bar, you are performing a `GET` request. That's the default behavior of the browser. Deal with it.

When performing a `GET` request to an endpoint that only supports `POST`, the expected result is a `405` error:

> [**6.5.5.  405 Method Not Allowed**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)
>
> The `405` (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method
> received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not
> supported by the target resource. [...]

### Picking the right tool

The browser address bar won't give you much flexibility to test a REST API, once you only can perform `GET` requests from it.

To test a REST API, you should use the *right tools*. They will give you the ability to perform requests using [all the HTTP methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3), set [request headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5) and other features that are not available in the browser address bar.

Just listing a few:

- [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)
- [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) (Chrome extension)
- [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) (Chrome extension)